# Show Kafka producer ip/port as a field in Kibana, logstash add_field?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, kibana

I have logstash with ElasticSearch & Kibana 7.6.2
I connect logstash to Kafka as follows:

```
input {
 kafka {
   bootstrap_servers => "------"
   topics_pattern => ["----"]
   decorate_events => true   
 }
}
filter {
 mutate { add_field => { "[topic_name]" => "%{[@metadata][kafka][topic]}"} }
 mutate { add_field => { "[ip_port]" => "X*X*X*X*X*X*X"} }
 date   { match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ] }
}
output {
 elasticsearch {
  hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  index => "logstash"
  document_type => "logs"
 }
}
```

What should I replace instead of `X*X*X*X*X*X*X` to have messages' producers IP/Port?
I mean Client IP of producers when they publish the message into Kafka.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such information in the [metadata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html#_metadata_fields). I think that if you want to know who published the message into Kafka you will need to send this information inside the message itself.

Comment: @leandrojmp Thanks